# The plethora of power management tags - what to do?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

We have a large number of power management related tags:

- [power-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/power-management)
- [suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/suspend)
- [standby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/standby)
- [hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hibernate)

There is also tag [shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shutdown) which is used in conjunction with power management but should be allowed to survive because of its other potential non-power-management uses.

Do you think it would be acceptable to merge [suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/suspend), [standby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/standby), and [hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hibernate) into [power-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/power-management) and then create each of these tags as a synonym of [power-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/power-management)?

Comment: Of course, this is after we check the tags.

Comment: Why do ya need to limit the amount of available tags?

Comment: I'd merge suspend with standby, but not with hibernate. Neither suspend nor hibernate are directly related to power-management, imho.